# Getting jsp value in javascript file

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have the following code in abc.jsp:

```
<%@page import="soundcap.Soundcap"%>

<%

    Soundcap cfl = new Soundcap();
    var sfl = cfl.playFile();

%>
```

I need the value of sfl in an external javascript file (jcode.js).  How can I get this value (sfl) from jsp in javascript?

Comment: Just `out.print()` it directly in the JS file.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to get it into a variable like this var xy = ...   what is ...?

Comment: Something like my answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to let JavaScript use the variable from server side?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348265/how-to-let-javascript-use-the-variable-from-server-side/14348580#14348580)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions.  Your suggestions make sense to me but this stuff isn't just working.  I am going through the entire code right now to see why it isn't working.  I think its probably from my end.  Thanks!

Comment: Your (you both) suggestions are quite valid. True, it wasn't working in my external .js file, but when I copied the script into index.jsp, it works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use this...

```
<%
//get your sfl
 %>
  <input type="hidden" id="sfl" value="<%=sfl%>">
```

in your js file use

```
var sfl=document.getElementById("sfl").value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just place your JSP value in input tag like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="value" value="${value}">
```

And get this value in JS like this:

```
var value = document.getElementById("value").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple:

```
<% 
//get your sfl
%>

<script>
var xyz = <% out.print(sfl); %>;
</script>
```

Comment: It didn't work.  Please note that I am using an external javascript.

Comment: Then put the code from my answer in your external javascript file (after removing the script tags). @bdfios